# Consolidating similar arrayformula functions in ranges of columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

A **Source** worksheet with a **Desired output** that repeats the use of 2 unique formulas varying only in cell locations (as shown below in table named **Code**).

Can the "unique" Arrayformulas be combined so that I might only use 1 of each in 2 cells (ie A1, B1) and specify the output cells, instead of duplicating the unique formulas?

I am using the following 5 formulas to achieve the output where the 2 unique sets of formulas are #s 1,3 and 2,4,5:

1. `=ArrayFormula(Source!A1:A3)` is in A1 and output values in A1:A3
2. `=ArrayFormula(if(Source!B1:B3="yes",1,2))` is in B1 and output values in B1:B3
3. `=ArrayFormula(Source!C1:C3)` is in C1 and output values in C1:C3
4. `=ArrayFormula(if(Source!D1:D3="yes",1,2))` is in D1 and output values in D1:D3
5. `=ArrayFormula(if(Source!E1:E3="yes",1,2))` is in E1 and output values in E1:E3

While I am using only 2 unique codes here, it should be appreciated that this might actually include many more than 2 unique codes with the goal of reducing duplication of arrayformulas that are essentially accomplishing the same thing.

**Source**

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Yes | Kelly | No | No |
| 2 | Shelly | No | Michelle | Yes | No |
| 3 | Michael | Yes | William | No | No |

**Desired output**

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 | Kelly | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | Shelly | 2 | Michelle | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Michael | 1 | William | 2 | 2 |

**Code**

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | =ArrayFormula(Source!A1:A3) | =ArrayFormula(if(Source!B1:B3="yes",1,2)) | =ArrayFormula(Source!C1:C3) | =ArrayFormula(if(Source!D1:D3="yes",1,2)) | =ArrayFormula(if(Source!E1:E3="yes",1,2)) |
| 1 | John | 1 | Kelly | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | Shelly | 2 | Michelle | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Michael | 1 | William | 2 | 2 |

Comment: In this case scenario of  lets say 5 columns; how do you visualize the ideal expected formula could be if you were to phrase it formula style?!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below formula in 1st cell i.e., A1

```
=ArrayFormula(if(Source!A1:E3="yes",1,if(Source!A1:E3="no",2,Source!A1:E3)))
```

You will get your desired output.

You may add multiple conditions by adding more nested if statements.